# How to display image overlay on video in external playback mode of AVPlayer via AirPlay?

Tags: ios, swift, overlay, avplayer, airplay

How to add an overlay `UIImage` in PNG format (such as a logo) with alpha channel on top of video playback, especially in case of external playback mode of `AVPlayer` when video is casted on `Apple TV` via `AirPlay`?

I would like add an overlay `UIImage` in PNG format with alpha channel (such as a logo) on top of video playback. This can be easily done on the phone by using contentOverlayView of `AVPlayerViewController`. However, when the video is casted and played on Apple TV via AirPlay, the contentOverlayView does not display.

I also tried to apply customised `UIImageView` on external screen when `UIScreen` has detected the external screen. However, the image still does not show. Instead, only the video playback is shown on the external screen. Here you can see my code for this approach:

```swift
if UIScreen.screens.count > 1 {
    let externalScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
    print("Playing: externalScreen.bounds: \(externalScreen.bounds)")

    let secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: externalScreen.bounds)

    secondWindow.screen = externalScreen

    let overlayImage = UIImage(named: "rain.png")
    let overlayImageView = UIImageView(frame: externalScreen.bounds)
    overlayImageView.image = overlayImage

    secondWindow.addSubview(overlayImageView)

    secondWindow.isHidden = false
    secondWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

It does not sound like a difficult problem as adding overlay views like subtitle or image logo seems to be very common operations. Can somebody help?

Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting, what I would suggest is seeing if you can get a dead simple example of air-play and view composition working by itself. So, create an image view with a background image and then place a transparent "over" image over that and see if both show up as expected on the device. This would require that the view composition would be done on the device before the results were sent over the air. This test would not involve movie playback, so it is very simple.

Comment: A solution I found is to create an ```AVPlayerLayer``` as a layer of the external screen and then put another ```CALayer``` with my PNG image on top of the ```AVPlayerLayer```. However, this approach only works if the property ```usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive```of the ```AVPlayer``` is set to ```false```. If the property is ```true``` (which is the case I need for FairPlay streaming), the ```AVPlayer``` seems to render the content automatically on external screen. Do you have any clue how to get the ```UIView``` of the ```AVPlayer``` when external playback mode is on?@MoDJ

Comment: @fkeufss did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same issue